# In Google Maps is there a way to set your home location?

Tags: google-maps

When finding bus information on Google Maps, is there an easy way to have it remember my home location so I don't have to type in my address each time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set your home and work locations in [My Places](http://maps.google.com/maps/myplaces). There is more info on the google map help site: [Home and Work in Maps](http://support.google.com/maps/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1626958)

Comment: Thanks! So now I just need to enter `home` and `work` in points A and B right? Is there a way to make the default bus instead of car?

Comment: If you type home (or work) the autocomplete will show your address--you may need to arrow down or click on the full address to select the address.
I don't know of a way to change the default mode of transportation.